# How do I exit a function, but continue with the rest of my program

Tags: c++

From what I've gathered from professor Google, just use return. But my compiler is telling me that I must return a value (I use Visual Studio Community 17).

Basically, I have an overloaded * operator that performs matrix multiplication. I've tested the program and it runs just fine. But I wanted to add conditions of what to do if a user tries to pass matrices that do not have their product defined.

```
/*
    overloaded * operator allows proper matrix multiplication
*/
Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &right)
{
    if (cols== right.rows)
    {
        Matrix temp(rows, right.cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < right.cols; ++j)
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; ++k)
                    temp.matrix[i][j] += matrix[i][k] * right.matrix[k][j];

        return temp;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "You can only multiply matrices if the number of columns of matrix A is equal to the number of rows of matrix B\n"
             << "Try changing the attributes of your matrix\n";

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about exceptions, yet?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, I have not.

Comment: What about return `this`?

Comment: @chbchb55 If I use return this, then I think it would allow the user to believe that it executed properly, when I want them to know they need to make changes.

Comment: Well, in that case, you should learn about them. This is what exceptions are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function currently crosses-concerns: it performs a self-contained data operation normally, but in an error condition it writes directly to `cout` - this is not how you should design software.

In idiomatic C++, your program should `throw` an `std::exception` object or subclass. I recommend `std::runtime_error` for this particular scenario:

Your code should look like this:

```
using namespace std;

...

Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &right)
{

    if( this->rows != right.cols ) {

        throw runtime_error("Invalid 'right' argument.");
    }

    // continue as normal
}
```

Calls should then by wrapped with `try/catch` block:

```
Matrix newMatrix;
try {

    newMatrix = leftMatrix * rightMatrix;
}
catch(runtime_error& e) {

    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Observe that the function is no-longer concerned with *how* the error is displayed - consumers of your code are now free to display the error message through `cout` or some other means, such as a web-application, an error log file, a GUI messagebox, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, I should probably just create another function that checks if the conditions are valid BEFORE I try to use the operator* on them?

Comment: What you should do is read the chapter in your C++ book that explains exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

So you have:

```
Matrix a,b;
Matrix c=a*b;
```

what do you want the state of the program to be after the `c=a*b` line when `a*b` makes no sense due to mismatched dimensions?

There are a few decent answers.

One of them is to print an error and end the program.

One of them is to throw an exception.

One of them is to augment the type of the matrices with their size, and make `c=a*b` only compile if the dimensions are matching.

One of them is to log an error and return a "null" Matrix of some kind, or one containing the error.

One of them is to make `*` return a Maybe type (like `std::optional` or `std::experimental::expected`), then force the caller to make the decision on how to handle failure (which is just the above, but with a separate template to handle nullable/error monads instead of baking it into Matrix itself).

One of them is to call a global or locally installed error callback that decides which one of the above to use.

In C++ you have to decide how you are going to handle errors.  The language does not choose for you.  But the decision matters, and there is no one right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is telling you to return a value, try using return 0 on the second return statement as well as setting a global flag. That way you can check if the matrix is valid or not without producing a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler asks you to return a value in your function because **operators** must return a value.

In the `else` part of your if you need to manage an exception, if you havn't reach there in proramming then just return an emoty matrix (your function's return type)